# What are the mathematical models of memory?

Tags: memory, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, mathematical-psychology

Are there mathematical models of memory in humans or animals?

I want to know how neuroscientists use mathematics to describe memory in living creatures. **How do neuroscientists model memory and show how it works by mathematics?**

I am a theoretical physics PhD student, and interested in neuroscience too. The only tool which I have and I could use to study neuroscience is mathematics and programing. That's why I want to know how neuroscientists address the memory by mathematics. I know how math works to describe neurons oscillations and action potential, but I don't know how it works for memory.

Any reference or review article is welcome too.

Comment: The cellular models of memory involve plenty of math but those models are only half the story. At the psychological level, we know a lot more about memory as a phenomenon but that knowledge is not encapsulated by any grand formal model. In any case, here are the mathematical models of plasticity which is thought to be a mechanism underlying memory formation. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Models_of_synaptic_plasticity

Comment: Surprised that nobody mentioned Hopfield network.

Comment: A user (who deleted the post) mentioned [the homepage for the University of Pennsylvania's Computational Memory Lab](http://memory.psych.upenn.edu/Main_Page).

Comment: @Memming Hopfield network lacks too many properties in human memory. That model was only well-known in Computer Science, not Cognitive Science.

Comment: Our small contribution to the topic https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0088823

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very many references may easily be found with [a Google search for "mathematical model memory"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematical+model+memory). Probably the most classic and iconic reference is [Atkinson and Shiffrin <sup><sub>(1965)</sub></sup>](http://www.rca.ucsd.edu/selected_papers/IMSSS_79.pdf), which is also [described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkinson%E2%80%93Shiffrin_memory_model). Its three components and their relationships are nicely encapsulated in this figure:

[image]

Many other, lesser-known mathematical models of memory exist, including but not limited to these:

- A model of recognition memory <sup><sub>(Atkinson & Juola, 1974)</sub></sup>
- A model of the circular process in short-term memory <sup><sub>(Min'ko & Petunin, 1981)</sub></sup>
- An application of interference theory to memory retention failures <sup><sub>(Anninos, 1972)</sub></sup>
- A model of [hippocampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocampus#Role_in_memory) activity involving affine and chaotic rules <sup><sub>(Yamaguti, Kuroda, Fukushima, Tsukada, & Tsuda, 2011; see also Tsuda, Yamaguti, Kuroda, Fukushima, & Tsukada, 2008; Fukushima, Tsukada, Tsuda, Yamaguti, & Kuroda, 2009)</sub></sup>
- A computer simulation model of short-term learning <sup><sub>(Anderson, 1983; see also a simpler model proposed by Hicklin, 1976, cited in [a review of Anderson's article by Preece & Anderson, 1984](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/tea.3660210910/pdf))</sub></sup>
- A computer simulation model of [operant conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning) <sup><sub>(Bower, 1967; Mandler, 1967)</sub></sup>
- The Hopfield <sup><sub>([1982](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC346238/pdf/pnas00447-0135.pdf), [1984](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC345226/pdf/pnas00611-0151.pdf), [2006](http://arxiv.org/ftp/q-bio/papers/0609/0609006.pdf))</sub></sup> [neural network model of associative memory](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hopfield_network#Associative_memory) <sup><sub>([Rojas, 1996](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K13.pdf); see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network#Human_memory); thanks @Memming!)</sub></sup> describes neural activity as binary, the attributes of memories as [state space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space) locations, and the system as governed by a [Lyupanov function](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Lyapunov_function). Much more could be said about [artificial neural network models of memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Types_of_models) in general (e.g., [LSTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory), <sup><sub>[Hochreiter & Schmidhuber, 1997](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~itamar/courses/ECE-692/Bobby_paper1.pdf);</sub></sup> [ART](http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/art.html), <sup><sub>Carpenter & Grossberg, [1987a](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-26-23-4919&id=30891), [1987b](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.9588&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).</sub></sup>

You may also be interested in the following references:

- A book chapter, "Mathematical models of human memory" <sup><sub>(Raaijmakers, 2008)</sub></sup>
- A book, *Mathematical Models in Psychology* <sup><sub>(Restle, 1971)</sub></sup>
- [Rojas' <sup><sub>(1996)</sub></sup> entire book, *Neural Networks: A Systematic Introduction*](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf) seems pertinent. (And free!)

And a related question here, in which "memory" comes up twice:

- https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1391/4086

---

<sup>**References**

**·** Anderson, O. R. (1983). A neuromathematical model of human information processing and its application to science content acquisition. *Journal of Research in Science Teaching, 20*(7), 603–620.

**·** Anninos, P. A. (1972). Mathematical model of memory trace and forgetfulness. *Kybernetik, 10*(3), 165–167.

**·** Atkinson, R. C., & Juola, J. F. (1974). Search and decision processes in recognition memory. In D. H. Krantz, R. C. Atkinson, R. D. Luce, & P. Suppes (Eds.), *Contemporary developments in mathematical psychology: I. Learning, memory and thinking*. Oxford, England: W. H. Freeman.

**·** Atkinson, R. C., & Shiffrin, R. M. (1965). Mathematical models for memory and learning. *Technical Report No. 79: Psychological Series.* Institute for Mathematical Studies in the Social Sciences, Stanford University. Retrieved from http://www.rca.ucsd.edu/selected_papers/IMSSS_79.pdf.

**·** Bower, G. (1967). A multicomponent theory of the memory trace. In K. W. Spence & J. T. Spence (Eds.), *The psychology of learning and motivation: I*. Oxford, England: Academic Press.

**·** Carpenter, G. A., & Grossberg, S. (1987). ART 2: Self-organization of stable category recognition codes for analog input patterns. *Applied Optics, 26*(23), 4919–4930. Retrieved from http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-26-23-4919&id=30891.

**·** Carpenter, G. A., & Grossberg, S. (1987). A massively parallel architecture for a self-organizing neural pattern recognition machine. *Computer Vision, Graphics, and Image Processing, 37*(1), 54–115. Retrieved from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.9588&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

**·** Fukushima, Y., Tsukada, M., Tsuda, I., Yamaguti, Y., & Kuroda, S. (2009). Coding mechanisms in hippocampal networks for learning and memory. In *Advances in Neuro-Information Processing* (pp. 72–79). Springer: Berlin Heidelberg.

**·** Hicklin, W. J. (1976). A model for mastery learning based on dynamic equilibrium theory. *Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 13*(1), 79–88.

**·** Hochreiter, S., & Schmidhuber, J. (1997). Long short-term memory. *Neural Computation, 9*(8), 1735–1780. Retrieved from http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~itamar/courses/ECE-692/Bobby_paper1.pdf.

**·** Hopfield, J. J. (1982). Neural networks and physical systems with emergent collective computational abilities. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 79*(8), 2554–2558. Retrieved from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC346238/pdf/pnas00447-0135.pdf.

**·** Hopfield, J. J. (1984). Neurons with graded response have collective computational properties like those of two-state neurons. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 81*(10), 3088–3092. Retrieved from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC345226/pdf/pnas00611-0151.pdf.

**·** Hopfield, J. J. (2008). Searching for memories, Sudoku, implicit check bits, and the iterative use of not-always-correct rapid neural computation. *Neural Computation, 20*(5), 1119–1164. Retrieved from http://arxiv.org/ftp/q-bio/papers/0609/0609006.pdf.

**·** Mandler, G. (1967). Organization and memory. In K. W. Spence & J. T. Spence (Eds.), *The psychology of learning and motivation: I*. Oxford, England: Academic Press.

**·** Min'ko, A. A., & Petunin, Y. I. (1981). Mathematical modeling of short-term memory. *Cybernetics, 17*(2), 287–298.

**·** Preece, P. F., & Anderson, O. R. (1984). Mathematical modeling of learning. *Journal of Research in Science Teaching, 21*(9), 953–955. Retrieved from http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/tea.3660210910/pdf.

**·** Raaijmakers, J. G. W. (2008). Mathematical models of human memory. In *Learning and Memory: A Comprehensive Reference, Vol. 2: Cognitive Psychology of Memory* (pp. 445–466). Elsevier.

**·** Restle, F. (1971). *Mathematical models in psychology*. Harmondsworth: Penguin.

**·** Rojas, R. (1996). *Neutral networks: A systematic introduction*. Springer. Retrieved from http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf.

**·** Tsuda, I., Yamaguti, Y., Kuroda, S., Fukushima, Y., & Tsukada, M. (2008). A mathematical model for the hippocampus: Towards the understanding of episodic memory and imagination. *Progress of Theoretical Physics Supplement, 173*, 99–108.

**·** Yamaguti, Y., Kuroda, S., Fukushima, Y., Tsukada, M., & Tsuda, I. (2011). A mathematical model for Cantor coding in the hippocampus. *Neural Networks, 24*(1), 43–53.</sup>

Comment: I'll try to keep tacking on other examples and references as I come across them, but I'd welcome others' edits (or upvote their separate answers) too.

Comment: @potpie also mentioned: "One lab [[Computational Memory Lab](http://memory.psych.upenn.edu/Main_Page)] that comes to mind right now working on topics related to the modeling of memory" Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a physics background, you may be particularly interested in [Sparse Distributed Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_distributed_memory), a model that provides a number of psychologically plausible characteristics, and is also neuroscientifically plausible.

The model and some of its characteristics are summarized in [this paper](http://journal.frontiersin.org/Journal/10.3389/fnhum.2014.00222/full).

Many great references have been provided by Nick Stauner, but this model is, in my view, one of the most promising and comprehensive ones in Cognitive Science.

Answer (score 1):

My lab uses the Semantic Pointer Architecture (where vectors are used as pointers between different dimensions, for more information check out "How to Build a Brain" by Chris Eliasmith) which is a Vector Symbolic Architecture (where sparse vectors represent symbols) to model working memory in a biologically plausible manner. So far this has been used in [Spaun](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/files/publications/eliasmith.2012.pdf) in it's model of serial memorization, as well as various other cognitive tasks such as the n-back task (soon to be published).

Answer (score 0):

Memory is a big word. Usually, neuroscientists and psychologists will try to model a specific cognitive process: for example, long-term recognition memory (the ability to distinguish between previously learned items and new items). Here is a link to a very good introductory text in computational neuroscience (which includes a section about memory and learning): http://grey.colorado.edu/CompCogNeuro/index.php?title=CCNBook/Main

Here is a link to a bible of neural networks: http://www.ru.lv/~peter/zinatne/ebooks/The%20MIT%20Press%20-%202003%20-%20The%20Handbook%20of%20Brain%20Theory%20and%20Neural%20Networks%20-%202nd%20Edition%20-%20ISBN%200262011972%20-%201309s%20-%20TLFeBOOK.pdf